# HTML5 canvas distance and move object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm have distance function who return: `distance` something like: 15, 10, etc.
Here function:

```
var Distance = function( other ) {
var xd = other.x - this.x;
var yd = other.y - this.y;
return Math.sqrt( xd * xd + yd * yd );
};
```

and have Bullet function who have position in `this.x = 10; this.y = 10;`

But how to move my Bullet with distance? Something like in Tower Defence games when Towers shoots to enemys?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English language.

Answer (score 0):

Your bullet likely moves as a function of `dt` and its velocity.  The distance to potential targets is a feature of the collision detection, which should be evaluated independently.